# e.__type is undefined CodeBuild Project Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

While creating a CodeBuild project which has 2 sources: 1 from S3 bucket & other from AWS CodeCommit repository, and artifact [output] into a S3 bucket, CodeBuild project creation fails at

```
e.__type is undefined
```

What's the cause?

Comment: Do you have more log data? What is the context of this error? Where does it occur? From your `buildspec.yml`?

Comment: This is while creating a CodeBuild project so I don't know where are the logs stored at the time of project creation using AWS Console. It occurs after clicking `Create build project`. Not from `buildspec.yml` it is thrown in general while creating the Codebuild project for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error and then I realized I was logged out from AWS. Maybe it's your case too. (After I logged in, the error went away.)

Comment: It was the problem in my case too. My session had expired. Although the codebuild project tab didn't show it that way.